# Find intersection of two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a dataset with two columns, one has area names and one has timings. I have found the topmost frequently occurring area names as well as times. 
Now, I wish to find how many times, these two occur together, as in how many times do I have a frequently occurring name and a frequently occurring time in the same row.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
a = (3,1,93,34,29) #topmost frequntly occurring areas 
b = (8,9,17,18,7) #topmost frequently occurring timings (in 24 hr)

def update(df):
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if df.iloc[i,0] == any(a):
           if df.iloc[i,9] == any(b):
              arr1.append(df.iloc[i,:])

update(df)
```

it just gives an empty array:

In [40]: arr1
Out[40]: []

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem would be to extract just the rows containing the topmost frequently occuring areas and from this subset of data, select just the rows that contain the topmost frequent times.